# MapControl doesn't display a BingMap on mobile emulator

Tags: mobile, uwp, emulation, bing-maps, uwp-maps

i am working on a uwp application.
I use a MapControl displaying a map from BingMaps. Everything works perfectly when i debug on my machine but when i debug on a mobile emulator the map doesn't display (instead there is a blue background).

I've also tried with the MapControl sample from the uwp samples found on github, and i have exactly the same issue.

Does someone have an idea about this problem ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the problem of your mobile emulator's version. I discussed this problem with my Colleague before, and I tested in the latest version of mobile emulator, the `MapControl` can be displayed.

Comment: You're perfectly right ! Thank you very much. As you said, i've downloaded the new version of emulators and it works like a charm now!